# Get time of specific timezone

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone

I am using a JavaScript `Date` class & trying to get the current date using `getDate()` method. But obviously it is loading system date & time. I am running the code from India but I want to get the date & time of UK using the same method. How can I do that ?

Comment: This thread is a poor cousin to the much more complete thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript which has a much better answer. Executive summary... use https://github.com/mde/timezone-js

Comment: @BrettHannah Executive summary would be to use [moment.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript/18612568#18612568) as timezone-js does [not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript#comment27512245_10089167) support DST ;-)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you know the UTC offset then you can pass it and get the time using the following function:

```
function calcTime(city, offset) {
    // create Date object for current location
    var d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // subtract local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time for city"+ city +" is "+ nd.toLocaleString();
}

alert(calcTime('Bombay', '+5.5'));
```

Taken from: [Convert Local Time to Another](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/)

Comment: Your `utc` thing is wrong. `d.getTime` *is* already in UTC milliseconds. Yet, instead of `toLocaleString()` you will need to use `.toUTCString()`!

Comment: Remember that the offset for a location can change (daylight savings/british summer time).

Comment: You actually need to be subtracting getTimezoneOffset output rather than adding it - that offset is for going from local time to UTC, not the other way around.

Comment: Is it possible to change the format? For example I only need the time in hours, minutes, seconds and AM/PM

Comment: @Bergi is correct your comment. I did what you mentioned and I get the correct date.

Comment: This is not a good answer.  If you hardcode in an offset you'll be off about half the year if it has daylight savings time.

Comment: @Bergi, your comment is wrong, the code is correct.

Comment: @kotekzot, you dont need that do that because the getTimezoneOffset method set the sign appropriately.

Comment: @MRC, there are a lot of method attached that Date object, so you can.

Comment: @horsejockey Unless you're using Arizona time, which never changes based on daylight savings time :-)

Answer (score 89):

You could use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-12.1).

```js
let options = {
    timeZone: 'Europe/London',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
  },
  formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);

console.log(formatter.format(new Date()));
```

Alternatively, if you're formatting just once instead of bulk use [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-13.3.2).

```
(new Date()).toLocaleString([], options)
```

Unfortunately browsers are *not* required to understand timezones other than UTC, so `try` these blocks and figure out an alternative in case it fails, for example fetch the timezone offset from a server.

Comment: This works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: correct answer, it is called the International API, and is built-in, in most newer browsers, you should check if it exists first.. naturally... - reference: [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)

Comment: This still does also not work in Safari.

Comment: This works very very well. Here's the listing of browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=Intl

Comment: Works in Google Sheets App Script.

Comment: List of time zones: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54500197. You may be interested in `America/Los_Angeles` and `America/New_York`

Answer (score 48):

One way to do this is to use getLocaleString, like this:

Create a date object:

```
date = new Date(0)
```

If you are in Berlin, this should convert to this string:

> Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

Get the hours in Athens:

```
date.toLocaleString('de-DE', {hour: '2-digit',   hour12: false, timeZone: 'Europe/Athens' })
```

> '02'

Get the hours in Shanghai:

```
date.toLocaleString('de-DE', {hour: '2-digit',   hour12: false, timeZone: 'Asia/Shanghai' })
```

> '08'

Comment: Side note: `Date.prototype.toLocaleString` only works on IE11+, Firefox 29+, Safari 11+, etc. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: not only this. the IANA timezone names are only available chrome and firefox..

Comment: First, you should use 'en-US' because it is the only locale supported in Node < 13 (ie. 100% of production Node use at this time), but also you need to account for minutes because some timezone have a half hour offset.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`getUTCDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate) and the related `getUTC...()` methods to access a time based off UTC time, and then convert.

If you wish, you can use [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf), which returns the number of seconds, in UTC, since the Unix epoch, and work with that, but it's likely going to be much more involved.

Answer (score 4):

### This is Correct way to get ##

```
function getTime(offset)
        {
            var d = new Date();
            localTime = d.getTime();
            localOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

            // obtain UTC time in msec
            utc = localTime + localOffset;
            // create new Date object for different city
            // using supplied offset
            var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
            //nd = 3600000 + nd;
            utc = new Date(utc);
            // return time as a string
            $("#local").html(nd.toLocaleString());
            $("#utc").html(utc.toLocaleString());
        }
```

Comment: Anyone if wondering how to call this function then here is an example if you want to get time for India

getTime(5.5);

Comment: All the suggested method in this thread doesn't consider day light saving (where it applies) so better use moment timezone library to make life easy.

Comment: Downvoting, because the answer expects the OP to know the offset. Presumably the OP is working from a time zone string although he is not explicit about this. The OP needs to use the Intl API, or a library like Luxon or Moment.

Comment: @AdamLeggett A simple Google search of nearly any location's time has UTC+/-# in the proprietary result, so it is a bit unfair to assume the OP is incapable of such a simple task.

Comment: @AbandonedCart the answer isn't general enough for most programmatic purposes unless it includes the answer of how to retrieve the offset. This is by no means simple - the offset can vary throughout the year and has changed at least several times in most locales through history. A database of all this is large.

Comment: @AdamLeggett Please share your answer, but try to keep it somewhat efficient.

Comment: @AbandonedCart this is why we have Intl.DateTimeFormat.

Comment: @AdamLeggett That seems like a method, but lacks any context.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really important that you have the correct date and time; it's best to have a service on your server (which you of course have running in UTC) that returns the time. You can then create a new Date on the client and compare the values and if necessary adjust all dates with the offset from the server time.

Why do this? I've had bug reports that was hard to reproduce because I could not find the error messages in the server log, until I noticed that the bug report was mailed two days *after* I'd received it. You can *probably* trust the browser to correctly handle time-zone conversion when being sent a UTC timestamp, but you obviously cannot trust the users to have their system clock correctly set. (If the users have their timezone incorrectly set too, there is not really any solution; other than printing the current server time in "local" time)

Answer (score 1):

> before you get too excited this was written in 2011

if I were to do this these days I would use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat). Here is a link to give you an idea of what type of [support this had in 2011](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_datetimeformat)

#### original answer now (very) outdated

Date.getTimezoneOffset()

The getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time difference between Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) and local time, in minutes.

For example, If your time zone is GMT+2, -120 will be returned.

Note: This method is always used in conjunction with a Date object.

```
var d = new Date()
var gmtHours = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
document.write("The local time zone is: GMT " + gmtHours);
//output:The local time zone is: GMT 11
```

Answer (score -1):

The `.getTimezoneOffset()` method should work. This will get the time between your time zone and GMT. You can then calculate to whatever you want.