# get browser time_zone in formate UTC 11:30,0 using jquery

Tags: jquery

any one give me suggestion to get browser time_zone in formate 'UTC +11:30,0'
   using jquery , because i want to store only   'UTC +11:30,0' in my data base

Answer (score 0):

**[CHECK THIS...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/how-to-get-time-of-specific-timezone-using-javascript)**

```
function calcTime(city, offset) {
    // create Date object for current location
    var d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time for city"+ city +" is "+ nd.toLocaleString();
}

alert(calcTime('Bombay', '+5.5'));
```