# How to get time till new year depending on location?

Tags: javascript, html

*I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/how-to-get-time-of-specific-timezone-using-javascript) which gets date of a one time zone from another time zone but what I want is to find out which timezone the user is in and then get date accordingly.*

My [website](http://2016newyear.weebly.com/) is current using this script to count the time till new year. I just realized that if the user is on a different time zone the timer will not be correct. So how do I find the time difference between the present date and new year depending on the users location.

```
    var daysSpan = document.getElementById("days");
    var hoursSpan = document.getElementById("hours");
    var minutesSpan = document.getElementById("minutes");
    var secondsSpan = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var c=1;
    function updateClock(){
        var t = Date.parse('January 1 2016 00:01:05') - Date.parse(new Date());
        if (t<=0 && c==1)
        {
            c--;
            window.open("http://www.its2016.weebly.com","_self");
        }
        var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
        var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
        daysSpan.innerHTML = days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = hours;
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = minutes;
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = seconds;
    }
    setInterval(updateClock,1000);
```

Comment: @misterion hey , that doesn't answer my question I had already check that out before.

Comment: Interesting, what's the reason you want trigger it 65 seconds later?

Comment: @vp_arth this is why https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110771/countdown-to-january-1-2016

Comment: `Date.parse('January 1 2016')-Date.now()` is enough, I think

Comment: @SOReadytoHelp, take a look to my answer for link, you provide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when you use `new Date();` it automatically get the local system hour.

See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, had a feeling the new Date() gets local time. Just wanted to clarify

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :) It's always a good thing to read the docs.
Also, try to get better on Google searching because I found the answer in less than two minutes.