# How to get Sri Lanka time abbreviation from Date() function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone

JavaScript Date() function returns IST(Indian Standard Time)
`Thu Apr 07 2016 17:24:07 GMT+0530 (IST)`.

From this I want to fetch the abbreviation. But this always returns the Indian standard time. How do I get the abbreviation for Srilanka time abbreviation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/how-to-get-time-of-specific-timezone-using-javascript don't wanna steal credit, but this seems to work just fine

Comment: Method given in above link requires city name.In my case, I won't be knowing city name. I just want the time abbreviation of the particular timezone. I have changed my system location to Sri Lanka

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you expect as the answer

```
const date = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Colombo'});
```

Comment: for the locale, instead of  'en-US', should be 'si-LK' for Sinhala language, or 'ta-LK' for Tamil language

Answer (score 1):

If you have set local time in your computer this will generate local time

```
   var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();  //  3/15/2017
   var dateTime =new Date().toLocaleString();   //  3/15/2017, 12:23:55 AM
   var time  =new Date().toLocaleTimeString();  //  12:23:55 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sri Lanka Time - is abbreviated as IST (India Standard Time)**.
So Sri Lanka TimeZone is same as that of India. Thats why you're getting IST, because it is IST.

Sri Lanka switched to SLST on 11th April 2011 midnight, but its same as IST, JavaScript probably doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Uh, no.  SLST and IST have been the same since 2006.  Nothing switched in 2011.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Lanka_Standard_Time and http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/sri-lanka/colombo?syear=2000&eyear=2020

Comment: I read about it here:
http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-slst-sri-lanka-standard-time-and-vs-ist-indian-standard-time/

Although, I did say its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var theDate = new Date(); 
    var res = theDate.replace("IST", "SLST");
}
</script>
```

And now you can use `res` to display the exact same time(since IST and SLST are the same according to what I've read), but with SLST instead of IST at the end. If there's more to replace in the string that `Date()` generates, then you can replace that too.

Comment: Except not every implementation of `Date` will return `"IST"` in the string.  That's implementation dependent, and varies considerably across browsers.

Comment: Now that I think about it, to get rid of all possible fallpits, there's a bunch to consider. I was just thinking using var UTCtime = (new Date()).toUTCString(); and then calculating the difference between that and the current timezone's time, storing it in "var offset" and use that, but there's more to it than that. Don't have the time for that right now.

Answer (score 0):

The string that JavaScript's `Date` function returns when you call `.toString()` on an instance, or when you implicitly cast to a string such as when writing to the console, is completely implementation dependent.  You are not guaranteed to be able to get *any* time zone abbreviation at all.  Some browsers may give an abbreviation, but others may spit out an entire time zone name, such as "Indian Standard Time", and others may just give an offset from UTC or GMT, such as "GMT+05:30".  There's nothing in the ECMAScript spec that makes this string anything in particular.

Additionally, recognize that time zone abbreviations can be ambiguous.  "IST" might stand for "Indian Standard Time", "Israel Standard Time", or "Ireland Standard Time".

More-so, the abbreviation for Sri Lanka has been "IST" in the time zone database since the switch from +06:00 to +05:30 that occurred in 2006.  Before that, the abbreviation "LKT" was used in the database.  You can read the entire history [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2016c/asia#L2564-L2637).  [Wikipedia shows an abbreviation of "SLST"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Lanka_Standard_Time), but this isn't implemented in any of the databases that are used for time zones in computing.  If you have first-hand knowledge of this abbreviation to be in common use, you could request it to be updated via [the tz discussion list at IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

In summary - if your system time zone is set for Sri Lanka (`Asia/Colombo` on Linux/Mac or  `Sri Lanka Standard Time|(UTC+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura` on Windows) and the JavaScript `Date` object is showing `IST` in your particular browser, then it is doing everything correctly and you should not attempt to change it.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you the answer

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

[link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_current)