# How to always show specific timezone's time on website with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show on my website current india time using javascript and i need to access the hour,min,sec,day because i want to make a ticking clock with that

I now if we have a new Date() object we can do this via

```
     currentTime = new Date();

     var h = currentTime.getHours();
     var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
     var s = currentTime.getSeconds();
```

But this method shows the local time of the user i want to always show the Indian time doesn't matter where the user is. How I can input the offset  in the new date object so that it gives me Indian time

I tried this

```
   utc = new Date().getTime();

  var current_indian_Time = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
```

But this is not working

There is too many answers on the StackOverflow i am totally confused. Thanks

Comment: do you consider in using a plugin? or just pure javascript?

Comment: @ShadowFiend If it is possible with javascript or jquery, It would be great, But if not possible, i can use plugin. Thanks

Comment: There's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/how-to-get-time-of-specific-timezone-using-javascript and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: You have `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` on your client which returns the offset in minutes. From there just add the offset of india to the date.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze ,artgb  Thanks guys for leading me to the right path.