# How to get server current date and time in JQuery

Tags: jquery, date, time

How to get server current date and time in JQuery?

My server time is in UK..

and we use in the system in India i get current date and time in JQuery it display India time.

But I want UK time in JQuery

Comment: Are you asking how to use jQuery to send an AJAX request to a server that will report its time?

Comment: No ajax checking countdown the display the time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time difference between UTC time and local time, in minutes.

and also with the help of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156749/how-do-i-substract-5-minutes-from-a-unix-timestamp) question, your answer will be this

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
var ans = new Date(d.getTime() + n * 60 * 1000);
console.log(ans.getHours()+':'+ans.getMinutes()+':'+ans.getSeconds());
```

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript) question and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/get-time-of-specific-timezone) one also helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can get the current date and time using the Date object

```
var now = new Date();
```

in php this code return server

```
<? echo '{serverTime: new Date(' . time()*1000 .')}';?>
```

or test this code

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i use this in but setInterval(function()) Jquery not working

Comment: How do you use this code? Do you want to have the current time realtime?