# Is there a smooth way to add function to different code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm setting up a code for a timer and I need to have the `currentTime`in the correct timezone. I have therefore to different `codes`. One `code` with the correct `currentTime` and the other `code`that is only doing `local`time. I am trying to add the `code` that has the correct `timezone`in to the other `code` but I can't get it work.

Here is the `code` with `timezone`:

```js
var $ = window.jQuery;

var setTime = function(){
  var date = moment().tz("Europe/Paris");
  
  var day = date.day();
      
  console.log('date', date);
  console.log('day', day);
  
  var time = date.format("h:mm A");
  
  console.log(time, time);
  
  $('#current-time').html("Current time: " + time + " ");
};

setTime();
```

And here is the `code` wit local time.

```js
var current = new Date();
var day = current.getDay();
var currentTime = (currentTime) = (current.getHours() * 60) + current.getMinutes();
var remainTime = 0;
var closeTime = (openTime[day].close *60);
var openTime = (openTime[day].open *60);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `Date()` function and calculate the offset of time.

For example:

```js
function calcTime(city, offset) {
    // create Date object for current location
    var d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // subtract local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time for the city "+ city +" is "+ nd.toLocaleString();
}

alert(calcTime('Paris', '+2'));
```

Retrieved from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/get-time-of-specific-timezone)