# Display current PDT time

Tags: javascript

PDT offset is -7 or -8 hours depending on daylight saving time.
I cannot simply subtract `7 * 60 * 60` from the UTC timestamp, as everybody else seems to be suggesting when googling this issue.

How can I simply alert(); the current current PDT time using Javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get time of specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/get-time-of-specific-timezone)

Comment: I just want to know why you can't subtract required number of millis from UTC timestamp?

Comment: Because the OP actually means "Pacific time" which is either PDT or PST depending on time of the year.

Comment: Yes, what @CherryDT says. That's also why other threads don't answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`toLocaleString`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) (there is also `toLocaleTimeString` if you don't need the date):

```js
alert(new Date('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z').toLocaleString(undefined, {
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
}))
// Output: 12/31/2019, 4:00:00 PM
```

This example uses a fixed time to show the relation between input and output. To use the *current* time, just use `new Date()` without initial value.

The first parameter is the locale. The `undefined` here means that it's the current system locale, so the *format* (not the timezone) will be based on the user's settings (for example, on my machine it outputs `31.12.2019, 16:00:00`). You can also set a fixed locale there if you want, for example `en-US`.

Comment: Thank you! So to show the *current* time I just leave Date() blank, right?